# combining data from multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets into summary workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which combines data from multiple workbooks(but only with one sheet) into summary workbook. I'm struggling with the code to change it for multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets but can't do it. Could you please help:

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()

Dim myPath As String, FilesInPath As String, lastrow As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet, mysht As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range, destRange As Range
Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer


'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Some"

'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    myPath = myPath & "\"
End If

'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
FilesInPath = dir(myPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
Fnum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    Fnum = Fnum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
    MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = dir()
Loop

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With


Set BaseWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
rnum = 1

'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
If Fnum > 0 Then
    For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(myPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
        Set mysht = mybook.Worksheet

        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

            On Error Resume Next




            'For i = 1 To Worksheets(i).Count
            'LastRow = Worksheets(i).Range("F" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            'MsgBox LastRow

            With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set sourceRange = Range("A6:I100") ' & LastRow)
            End With




                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If

                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        'For j = 1 To Worksheets(j).Count 'Worksheets.Count
                            With sourceRange
                                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                        Resize(.rows.Count).Value = Range("A2").Value 'MyFiles(Fnum)
                            End With

                         'Next j


                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destRange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destRange = destRange. _
                                            Resize(.rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destRange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount




                    End If

                End If

            'Next i

            mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If

    Next Fnum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If



ExitTheSub:
' Restore the application properties.
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As your question has *I'm struggling with the code* and *Could you please help* it's unclear if your current code errors when running or if it is missing the part you want. Based on this it's unlikely people will just try your code and try to read your mind. To get an answer (I'm presuming you're missing the part you want here) I suggest you add in an attempt and add information about which part's then not doing as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim kindly pointed out, it is unclear what you specifically want help with. However, the code I've included below should provide you with a *cookie-cutter* base that you take away and customise for your purposes. I've tested it, and it seems to work well. It will iterate through a range of workbooks that you select, and all of the sheets contained within.

I hope this helps

P.S Sorry for the messy code - I do not have the time to clean it up.

```
Sub MergeMultiple1()

Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim shLast As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim StartRow As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Add a new summary worksheet.
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"
' Fill in the start row.

currentfiles = selectedfiles()

For nfile = LBound(currentfiles) To UBound(currentfiles)
    Set oFS = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Filename = currentfiles(nfile)
    Set workbk1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
    StartRow = 1
' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
'Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
            ' Find the last row with data on the summary
            ' and source worksheets.
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)
            shLast = LastRow(sh)
            ' If source worksheet is not empty and if the last
            ' row >= StartRow, copy the range.

            If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
                'Set the range that you want to copy
                Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))
                ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
                ' worksheet to copy all the data.

                If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
                    "summary worksheet to place the data."
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                End If

                ' This statement copies values and formats.
                CopyRng.Copy
                rnga = DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")

            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "X").Value = workbk1.Name

        End If

    End If

Next
workbk1.Close
Next
ExitTheSub:

Application.GoTo DestSh.Cells(1)

DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With

End Function

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function selectedfiles()
selectedfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
filefilter:="Speadsheets, *.xl*; *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make a summary out of several worksheets but not workbooks I would recommend you to check this [procedure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbC2lGLFXS0) that explains in details how to create your own code adapted to your request.

Because most of the times, if you ask someone to fix your code you will not be able to debug it or to modify it in the future as it is often the case.